# render svg from d3.js on non-svg supported browsers, especially IE 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, d3.js, visualization

I am working on data visualization in d3.js, and my visualization works all SVG supported browsers. But it hasn't been great with the IE 8, and below. I have seen all various answers to this problem. There are javascript libraries such as R2D3, and D34Raphel. R2D3 library wasn't working for me.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="r2d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I got this error:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
r2d3.js, line 8434 character 7
```

I have also touched on D34Raphel, but never had any luck.

I was wondering if there are any other ways to work around this IE problem with SVG. I would like to still use D3.js.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated !

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to leave this question unanswered. I will just answer my own question. After some attempts of using different js libraries to help svg to display on IE8 and below. I have got a good successful rate with R2D3 library.

Thus, R2D3 library get my vote.